# Access 2010 Query counts double

Tags: ms-access-2010

all.

I've put together a very simple budget database in Access 2010. When I ran a query to find the sum of expenses in each category, I found the following results:

In some instances, the amounts added-up. I.e. I spent $240, and that's the amount returned.

In one case, the amount returned was double the amount entered. When I changed "Sum" to "Group By" in the query design module, it returned 6 records that added-up to half of the amount I found with "Sum." When I changed "Group By" to "Count," it returned the value 12.

In other case, I had similar results. However, in that category, I would find 33 records using "Group By," but when I used "Count," it returned the value 40.

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT tblType.typName, tblCategories.catName,
Sum(tblEntries.entAmount) AS SumOfentAmount,
tblBudgetParameters.budAmount
FROM tblVendors INNER JOIN (tblType INNER JOIN ((tblCategories INNER
JOIN tblBudgetParameters ON tblCategories.catID =
tblBudgetParameters.budItem) INNER JOIN tblEntries ON
tblCategories.catID = tblEntries.entCategory) ON
tblType.typIncomeExpenditure = tblEntries.entType) ON tblVendors.venID
= tblEntries.entVendor
WHERE (((tblEntries.entDate) Between [Enter Start Date] And [Enter End
Date]) AND ((tblBudgetParameters.budExpired)=False))
GROUP BY tblType.typName, tblCategories.catName, tblBudgetParameters.budAmount;
```

How do I find out what is doubling and how to fix it?

Thanks,
-Rob

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating tables one by one and get a count to find out which table is giving you the duplicates. For example:

```
SELECT tblVendors.VenID, Count(tblVendors.VenID)
FROM tblVendors 
INNER JOIN tblEntries 
ON tblVendors.venID = tblEntries.entVendor
HAVING Count(tblVendors.VenID) >1
```